# FreqDist on a list giving error 'unhashable type: list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nltk

I thought FreqDist took in a list and then have you back the counts? I have a list called ngrams

````
    ngrams = make_ngram_tuples(tokenized_sents, n)
    print(type(ngrams))
    dist = FreqDist(ngrams)
    print(type(ngrams))
    
    <class 'list'>```
But I also get the error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Any clue what could be going on?
````

Comment: What is `FreqDist` and where is it being called from? Please [edit] to show your imports to make this a [mcve]

Comment: What is the type of the items in the `ngrams` list? If `ngrams` is a list of lists, this could be giving rise to the error.

Comment: it is a list of lists.. I just don't know how to get around that

Answer (score 0):

If `ngrams` is a list of lists, as you've indicated in a comment to your question, then `FreqDist()` may be attempting to create a dictionary using the elements of `ngrams` as keys. This will be a problem, as the element datatype `list` is not hashable in Python. A `tuple` would be hashable, so you could try the following updated code to fix it by converting each `list` element within the `ngrams` `list` to a `tuple` before passing `ngrams` as an argument to `FreqDist()`:

```
    ngrams = make_ngram_tuples(tokenized_sents, n)
    ngrams = [tuple(v for v in ngrams)]
    dist = FreqDist(ngrams)
```